# adding elements to arraylist using a loop

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

My problem is very simple but i can't find the way to solve it. Basically i want to create an Arraylist and add elements to it using a loop(up to as many elements as i want). i'm using the netbeans gui, and whenever i press a button "add" i want to add the string variables name and capital to my arraylist and display it in a TextArea.
something like:

```
[london, england,america,united states etc..]
```

so far the only thing it does is print the two variables name and capital many times like:

```
[londonn, england, london, england etc..]
```

here is the code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String name, capital;
    ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
    name = jTextField1.getText();
    capital = jTextField2.getText();
    for(int i=0;i < 10;i++) {
        input.add(name);
        input.add(capital);
        jTextArea4.setText(String.valueOf(input));
    }      
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the for loop. Its because of this loop you are storing same value 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting your `ArrayList` to continually grow, then you need to make it a class variable and not a local variable to you `jButton1ActionPerformed`.

Also take out the `for` loop.  When you're adding a new name and capital, to your `ArrayList`, you only have to do it once.

Something like this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Make sure input is a class variable and it will continue to grow                                         
    input.add(jTextField1.getText());
    input.add(jTextField2.getText());
    jTextArea4.setText(String.valueOf(input));      
}
```

Once your `ArrayList` is a class variable, you're going to want a way to either clear the `ArrayList` or remove items from it.

Comment: @user3732562 You're welcome.  Kindly click the check mark to my answer, unless Jordan Doerksen's answer really fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to move `jTextArea4.setText(String.valueOf(input))` outside the `for loop`

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the following code outside the loop:

```
jTextArea4.setText(String.valueOf(input));
```

Comment: this is wrong becuase the aaraylist contains 10 elements . even if you do thsi the textfield will print all the 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the for loop becuase you are storing the same values more than one time.

you can do like this.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String name, capital;
ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
name = jTextField1.getText();
capital = jTextField2.getText();
    input.add(name);
    input.add(capital);
    jTextArea4.setText(String.valueOf(input));
```

}

here are getting the name and capital values from the text fields and stroing in into the arraylist and then display the values of the arraylist in teh textfield4..

if you want to add as much elements you can do but when you are setting the jtextField4 you have to get the last element from the input arraylist becuause the arraylist object contains 10 stings.

like this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String name, capital;
ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
name = jTextField1.getText();
capital = jTextField2.getText();
for(int i=0;i < 10;i++) {
    input.add(name);
    input.add(capital);
    jTextArea4.setText(String.valueOf(input.get(input.size)));
}
```

}

I hope this will help you.

Comment: yes thank you, all the answers have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove the loop. And if you want that arraylist to be useful you must make it a class level variable

```
ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String name, capital;
name = jTextField1.getText();
capital = jTextField2.getText();
    input.add(name);
    input.add(capital);
    jTextArea4.setText(String.valueOf(input));
```

}

Comment: You just duplicated my answer, also you're re-instantiating the ArrayList every time this event fires which prevents it from growing.

Comment: Sorry. I started typing before there were any answers then I got distracted before I submitted. On the mobile app you can't see if someone else posted an answer while you are typing